# Heroku deploying error

Tags: node.js, heroku, react-starter-kit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXN3t.png)    at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=thawing-harbor-62063.herokuapp.com request_id=f660858a-37c6-4a77-8940-cd7ca253bb6c fwd="76.164.216.25" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Above console is from `heroku logs -t`
When I type `heroku open`, application errors occur.

**An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.**

If anyone has ever faced this issue, please share solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue, the port of the server should be set to: `process.env.PORT`.

It's because heroku dinamicaly sets the port of the application.

I have also set the ip of the server to: `null`

**Update:**

From the image it seems the `@babel/preset-env` module is not included.

I hope this helps you!

**Update 2:**

The solution was to use `yarn run deploy` as you can see it in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In my opinion, this error occurs because of dev dependencies.
I added Image.

This is heroku console error.
Please check it and share your opinion
Thanks

Comment: Is '@babel/preset-env' module included in your package.json?

Comment: Put it into the "dependencies" too

Comment: of course, I have tried to do that.
But it still occurs error. 
And I solved my issue using `yarn run deploy`.
In fact, I was using react-starter-kit, which provides deploy function

Thanks for your help